# R convert between zoo object and data frame, results inconsistent for different numbers of columns?

Tags: r, dataframe, zoo

I have difficulty switching between data frames and zoo objects, particularly keeping meaningful column names, and inconsistencies between univariate and multivariate cases:

```
library(zoo)

#sample data, two species counts over time
t = as.Date(c("2012-01-01", "2012-01-02", "2012-01-03", "2012-01-04"))
n1 = c(4, 5, 9, 7)  #counts of Lepisma saccharina
n2 = c(2, 6, 0, 11) #counts of Thermobia domestica
df = data.frame(t, n1, n2)
colnames(df) <- c("Date", "Lepisma saccharina", "Thermobia domestica")

#converting to zoo loses column names in univariate case...
> z1 <- read.zoo(df[,1:2]) #time series for L. saccharina
> colnames(z1)
NULL
> colnames(z1) <- c("Lepisma saccharina") #can't even set column name manually
Error in `colnames<-`(`*tmp*`, value = "Lepisma saccharina") : 
  attempt to set colnames on object with less than two dimensions
#... but not in multivariate case
> z2 <- read.zoo(df) #time series for both species
> colnames(z2)
[1] "Lepisma saccharina"  "Thermobia domestica"
```

To go back from a zoo object to a data frame in the original format, it's not enough to use `as.data.frame` since it won't include a Date column (the dates end up in the rownames): more work is needed.

```
zooToDf <- function(z) {
    df <- as.data.frame(z) 
    df$Date <- time(z) #create a Date column
    rownames(df) <- NULL #so row names not filled with dates
    df <- df[,c(ncol(df), 1:(ncol(df)-1))] #reorder columns so Date first
    return(df)
}
```

This works great on the multivariate case, but clearly can't recover a meaningful column name in the univariate case:

```
> df2b <- zooToDf(z2)
> df2b
        Date Lepisma saccharina Thermobia domestica
1 2012-01-01                  4                   2
2 2012-01-02                  5                   6
3 2012-01-03                  9                   0
4 2012-01-04                  7                  11

> df1b <- zooToDf(z1)
> df1b
        Date z
1 2012-01-01 4
2 2012-01-02 5
3 2012-01-03 9
4 2012-01-04 7
```

Is there a simple way to handle *both* univariate *and* multivariate cases? It seems `z1` needs to remember the column name somehow.

Comment: Note to self: the basic problem of "drop" sometimes causing inconsistency between one and multi variable cases arises often with data frames, not just on conversion to zoo objects. See the FAQs for `data.table` http://datatable.r-forge.r-project.org/datatable-faq.pdf where the developers note "In `[.data.frame` we very often set `drop=FALSE`. When we forget, bugs can arise in edge cases where single columns are selected and all of a sudden a vector is returned rather than a single column data.frame. In `[.data.table` we took the opportunity to make it consistent and drop drop."

Comment: What is referred to as inconsistency in the question is how R works even without zoo.  In fact, zoo is consistent with how R works.  If it did not work that way it would be inconsistent.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To convert from data frame to zoo use `read.zoo`:

```
library(zoo)
z <- read.zoo(df)
```

Also note the availability of the `drop` and other arguments in `?read.zoo` .

and to convert from zoo to data frame, including the index, use `fortify.zoo`:

```
fortify.zoo(z, name = "Date")
```

(If ggplot2 is loaded then you can just use `fortify`.)

As mentioned in the comments below the question, the question as well as some of the other answers are either outdated or have some significant misunderstandings.  Suggest you review https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/zoo/vignettes/zoo-design.pdf which discusses the design philosophy of zoo which includes consistency with R itself.  Certainly zoo would be a lot harder to use if you had to remember one set of defaults for R and another for zoo.

Answer (score 16):

If you don't want to drop dimensions, use `drop=FALSE`:

```
R> (z1 <- read.zoo(df[,1:2], drop=FALSE))
           Lepisma saccharina
2012-01-01                  4
2012-01-02                  5
2012-01-03                  9
2012-01-04                  7
```

You can do something like `write.zoo` if you want to include the zoo index as a column in your data.frame:

```
zoo.to.data.frame <- function(x, index.name="Date") {
  stopifnot(is.zoo(x))
  xn <- if(is.null(dim(x))) deparse(substitute(x)) else colnames(x)
  setNames(data.frame(index(x), x, row.names=NULL), c(index.name,xn))
}
```

---

UPDATE:

After trying to edit your question for brevity, I thought of an easy way to create `df2b` to your specifications (this will also work for `z1` if you don't drop dimensions):

```
R> (df2b <- data.frame(Date=time(z2), z2, check.names=FALSE, row.names=NULL))
        Date Lepisma saccharina Thermobia domestica
1 2012-01-01                  4                   2
2 2012-01-02                  5                   6
3 2012-01-03                  9                   0
4 2012-01-04                  7                  11
```

Comment: fortify.zoo(z1)  ?

Answer (score 2):

There's a newer simple solution to this using the `timetk` package. It will convert several time series formats, including `xts` and `zoo`, to `tibble`s. Simply wrap in `as.data.frame` to get a data frame.

```
timetk::tk_tbl(zoo::read.zoo(df))
# A tibble: 4 x 3
  index      `Lepisma saccharina` `Thermobia domestica`
  <date>                    <dbl>                 <dbl>
1 2012-01-01                    4                     2
2 2012-01-02                    5                     6
3 2012-01-03                    9                     0
4 2012-01-04                    7                    11
```

Answer (score 0):

I would to go around a little bit. First, write the zoo to a csv file, then read it again to a data.frame. The index column will be named "Index" by default but you can change it with a parameter.

```
library(zoo)
date <-
  seq.Date(
    from = as.Date("2017-01-01"),
    to = as.Date("2017-01-10"),
    by = "days"
  )
value <- seq.int(from = 100, to = length(date))
vzoo <- zoo(value, date)
write.zoo(
  vzoo,
  index.name = "Date",
  file = "tmp.txt",
  sep = ",",
  col.names = TRUE
)
vzoo.df <- read.csv("tmp.txt", sep = ',')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply create a new data set and add the as.data.frame to wrap the fortify.zoo. This should help.
z2=as.data.frame(fortify.zoo(z, name = "Date"))