# Interpolate GPS points to other set of points in R

Tags: r, gps, interpolation, geospatial

I have two datasets: one of GPS points (from bus locations) with timestamps that are collected mostly at every 30 seconds, and other of intermediate points (from bus stops) that fall within the GPS trajectory.

```
# GPS Points
gps_points <- structure(list(id_gps = c(4138176L, 4136334L, 4134534L, 4132685L, 
4130891L, 4129035L, 4127232L, 4125387L, 4123620L, 4121861L, 4120114L, 
4118381L, 4116721L, 3380373L, 3374532L, 3369036L, 3363258L, 3357540L, 
3351543L, 3345549L, 3339777L, 3333210L, 3326793L, 3319251L, 3312822L, 
3306501L), hora = structure(c(1535953786, 1535953816, 1535953846, 
1535953876, 1535953906, 1535953936, 1535953966, 1535953996, 1535954026, 
1535954056, 1535954086, 1535954116, 1535954146, 1535954176, 1535954206, 
1535954236, 1535954266, 1535954296, 1535954326, 1535954356, 1535954386, 
1535954416, 1535954446, 1535954476, 1535954506, 1535954536), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), lon = c(-38.500763, -38.501413, -38.50252, 
-38.503505, -38.504694, -38.505441, -38.506651, -38.507328, -38.507965, 
-38.509063, -38.509735, -38.51022, -38.511546, -38.511778, -38.512788, 
-38.513633, -38.514568, -38.51495, -38.515331, -38.515878, -38.516438, 
-38.516628, -38.517129, -38.517651, -38.518056, -38.518358), 
    lat = c(-3.80892, -3.807633, -3.805113, -3.802854, -3.800343, 
    -3.79881, -3.796178, -3.79474, -3.793426, -3.791048, -3.789561, 
    -3.78856, -3.78569, -3.785216, -3.783108, -3.781245, -3.778751, 
    -3.777118, -3.775673, -3.773774, -3.771845, -3.771159, -3.769336, 
    -3.767198, -3.765478, -3.764019)), row.names = c(NA, -26L
), class = "data.frame", .Names = c("id_gps", "hora", "lon", 
"lat"))


# Stops
stops <- structure(list(stop_id = c(4873, 3215, 5083, 3346, 3363, 3362, 
3542, 3543, 3540, 4629, 3528), lon = c(-38.516766, -38.515311, 
-38.513903, -38.512154, -38.511001, -38.509844, -38.508943, -38.50816, 
-38.507062, -38.505798, -38.504044), lat = c(-3.771828, -3.77695, 
-3.781432, -3.785157, -3.787631, -3.790069, -3.791997, -3.793663, 
-3.796027, -3.798711, -3.802504)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -11L), .Names = c("stop_id", 
"lon", "lat"))
```

```
head(gps_points)
 id_gps                hora       lon       lat
1 4138176 2018-09-03 05:49:46 -38.50076 -3.808920
2 4136334 2018-09-03 05:50:16 -38.50141 -3.807633
3 4134534 2018-09-03 05:50:46 -38.50252 -3.805113
4 4132685 2018-09-03 05:51:16 -38.50350 -3.802854
5 4130891 2018-09-03 05:51:46 -38.50469 -3.800343
6 4129035 2018-09-03 05:52:16 -38.50544 -3.798810

head(stops)
stop_id       lon       lat
1    4873 -38.51677 -3.771828
2    3215 -38.51531 -3.776950
3    5083 -38.51390 -3.781432
4    3346 -38.51215 -3.785157
5    3363 -38.51100 -3.787631
6    3362 -38.50984 -3.790069
```

GPS points in red, stops in blue
[image]

**I want to estimate (through linear interpolation on the GPS dataset) the timestamp estimated associated with each stop using R.** The desired output would be the stops dataset with a new column identifying the interpolated timestamp.

The workaround I'm doing right now includes interpolating the GPS points to occurrences every 5 seconds (using [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26806140/interpolate-coordinates-at-unrecorded-timestamps)), then calculating the closest GPS occurrence at each stop (using `RANN::nn2`). The GPS dataset is very big, so this is computationally infeasible, and I still don't get the "exact" timestamp associated with each stop.

```
# workaround
# Crete combination of timestamps for each 5 seconds
full.time   <- with(gps_points,seq(gps_points$hora[1],tail(gps_points$hora,1),by=5))

library(zoo)
# convert to zoo object
df.zoo <- zoo(gps_points[,c("lon", "lat")],gps_points$hora)

# interpolate; result is also a zoo object
result <- na.approx(df.zoo,xout=full.time)

# transform zoo to df
zoo.to.data.frame <- function(x, index.name="hora") {
  stopifnot(is.zoo(x))
  xn <- if(is.null(dim(x))) deparse(substitute(x)) else colnames(x)
  setNames(data.frame(index(x), x, row.names=NULL), c(index.name,xn))
}

gps_points_interpolated <- zoo.to.data.frame(result) %>% as_tibble()

# Create temp_id for stops
stops <- stops %>%
  mutate(temp_id = 1:n())

# To each GPS point, what's the closest stop?
opa <- RANN::nn2(select(stops, lon, lat), select(gps_points_interpolated, lon, lat), 1)

vamos <- gps_points_interpolated %>%
  mutate(temp_id = opa$nn.idx, dist = opa$nn.dists*111320)

# Bring back stop_id, lon e lat of each stop
vamos <- left_join(vamos, stops, by = "temp_id", suffix = c(".gps", ".stop")) %>%
# Select columns
  select(stop_id, lon = lon.stop, lat = lat.stop, hora, dist)

# Select the observations that have minimun distance to each stop
vamos_fim <- vamos %>%
  group_by(stop_id) %>%
  slice(which.min(dist))

head(vamos_fim)
```

```
# A tibble: 6 x 5
# Groups:   stop_id [6]
  stop_id   lon   lat hora                dist[,1]
    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dttm>                 <dbl>
1    3215 -38.5 -3.78 2018-09-03 05:58:21     34.1
2    3346 -38.5 -3.79 2018-09-03 05:56:21     39.9
3    3362 -38.5 -3.79 2018-09-03 05:54:36     37.1
4    3363 -38.5 -3.79 2018-09-03 05:55:26     37.9
5    3528 -38.5 -3.80 2018-09-03 05:51:21     38.7
6    3540 -38.5 -3.80 2018-09-03 05:52:51     34.6
```

Methods other than linear interpolation would be welcome as well. Thanks.

Comment: @M-M I'm looking for help. I added the code I've used in the workaround.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this myself using the `zoo::na.approx` function. First, you need to calculate the cumulative distance between consecutive points **starting from the same point** in both datasets. In my example, my GPS points come first in the order, so I'll pick the first GPS point as the "starting point" of both datasets.

```r
# I just realized that the datasets are growing in opposite direction, so I'll flip the stops
stops <- map_df(stops, rev)


# Function to calculate distance from previous point

get.dist <- function(lon, lat) geosphere::distHaversine(tail(cbind(lon,lat),-1),head(cbind(lon,lat),-1))

# Calculate cumulative distance of gps points (points must be ordered by time)
gps_points <- gps_points %>%
  mutate(dist = c(0, cumsum(get.dist(lon, lat))))

# Input first GPS point and calculate cumulative distance of stops (also must be ordered)
stops <- gps_points %>%
  # Select only the first point  
  slice(1) %>%
  # Select columns to match the stops dataset
  mutate(stop_id = NA) %>%
  select(stop_id, lon, lat) %>%
  # Input the stop points
  rbind(stops) %>%
  # Calculate cumulative dist
  mutate(dist = c(0, cumsum(get.dist(lon, lat))))


# Interpolate ------------------------------
x <- gps_points$hora
y <- gps_points$dist

# to which position we want to interpolate? to the stops!
xout <- stops$dist

interp <- as.POSIXct(zoo::na.approx(x , 
                                    y, 
                                    xout = xout, 
                                    ties = "ordered",
                                    rule = 2), 
                     origin = "1970-01-01")

# Put it together
stops_interp <- stops %>%
  # Input the interpolated times
  mutate(hora = interp) %>%
  # Delete the first row that was inputed from the GPS
  slice(-1)

stops_interp
```

```r
   stop_id       lon       lat      dist                hora
1     3528 -38.50404 -3.802504  801.8295 2018-09-03 05:51:21
2     4629 -38.50580 -3.798711 1266.8446 2018-09-03 05:52:18
3     3540 -38.50706 -3.796027 1596.9692 2018-09-03 05:52:51
4     3543 -38.50816 -3.793663 1887.0162 2018-09-03 05:53:43
5     3542 -38.50894 -3.791997 2091.8550 2018-09-03 05:54:05
6     3362 -38.50984 -3.790069 2328.6658 2018-09-03 05:54:38
7     3363 -38.51100 -3.787631 2628.9530 2018-09-03 05:55:27
8     3346 -38.51215 -3.785157 2932.6796 2018-09-03 05:56:18
9     5083 -38.51390 -3.781432 3390.5980 2018-09-03 05:57:15
10    3215 -38.51531 -3.776950 3913.4700 2018-09-03 05:58:22
11    4873 -38.51677 -3.771828 4506.1116 2018-09-03 05:59:52
```

The column `hora` represents the interpolated time.

### Going further

However, this interpolation is based on the euclidean distance between points. What if I have the expected path (like a road) of both GPS points and stops? In that case, I would suggest using the `rgeos::gProject` function to calculate the cumulative distance of both GPS and stops in the path.