# transforming data into time series

Tags: r, dataframe, dataset, time-series, posixct

I have a csv data set that I would like t transform into time series data for time series analysis. 
The data looks like that (there are additional columns, and there are 17,190 obs.):

```
temp  interval

   10.0  2014-04-01 00:00:00

   10.0  2014-04-01 00:15:00

   10.0  2014-04-01 00:30:00

   10.0  2014-04-01 00:45:00

   7.8   2014-04-01 01:00:00
```

The Interval column is in `POSIXct` format.

I would appreciate help with the code for transforming it into time series please.

Thank you

Comment: Did you try anything? Googling your title gives [this as a first link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29046311/how-to-convert-data-frame-into-time-series-in-r)

Comment: yes, I did try some stuff including trying to use zoo package. Also, I tried what is described in the link you provided, but it converts the "interval" column into numbers that I can't quite understand.

Comment: Can you share the output of `dput(head(your_data))`?

Comment: In zoo, I think it's just `zoo(data)`, but your `data$interval` column for the time has to come first. E.g. - `read.zoo(dat[c("interval","temp")], drop=FALSE)` as per https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14064097/r-convert-between-zoo-object-and-data-frame-results-inconsistent-for-different

Answer (score 0):

CSV stands for *comma separated values*.  The data shown in the question is not in that form but if we assume that the data is a data frame `DF` shown reproducibly in the Note at the end then the following code gives a zoo series `z` and also converts it to a `ts` series `tt` where the times are the number of seconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00.  See `?read.zoo` for more information on that function. Also the zoo package contains an entire vignette with many `read.zoo` examples.

`z` can be used for plotting and `tt` might be useful if you are using functions that only accept `ts` class input.

```
library(zoo)
z <- read.zoo(DF, index = "interval", tz = "")
tt <- as.ts(z)
```

### Note

```
Lines <- "
temp  interval
   10.0  2014-04-01 00:00:00
   10.0  2014-04-01 00:15:00
   10.0  2014-04-01 00:30:00
   10.0  2014-04-01 00:45:00
   7.8   2014-04-01 01:00:00"

# read into separate lines, trim whitespace from ends and
#  replace 2 or more consecutive spaces with comma
L <- gsub("  +", ",", trimws(readLines(textConnection(Lines))))
DF <- read.csv(text = L)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you read in the csv with `read_csv` in `tidyverse` you'll get the interval column in POSIXct class automatically.

`dput` below:

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- structure(list(temp = c(10, 10, 10, 10, 7.8), interval = structure(c(1396310400, 
1396311300, 1396312200, 1396313100, 1396314000), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC")), class = c("spec_tbl_df", "tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -5L), spec = structure(list(
cols = list(temp = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
"collector")), interval = structure(list(format = ""), class = c("collector_datetime", 
"collector"))), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
"collector")), skip = 1), class = "col_spec"))
```

you can then just reorder cols and convert to zoo.

```
library(zoo)

df <- df %>% 
  select(interval, temp) %>% 
  zoo()

class(df)
[1] "zoo"
```